# why have a problem in my flutter code, error in dropdownDecoration,buttonHeight and buttonPadding?

Tags: flutter

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlTEA.png)

```
TextFormField(
                  controller: taskDescController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: null,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 20,
                      vertical: 20,
                    ),
                    icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.bubble_left_bubble_right,
                        color: Colors.cyan),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    const Icon(CupertinoIcons.tag, color: Colors.cyan),
                    const SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                    Expanded(
                      child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          isDense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          ),
                        ),
                        isExpanded: true,
                        value: widget.taskTag,
                        buttonHeight: 60,
                        buttonPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 10),
                        dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        items: taskTags
                            .map(
                              (item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: item,
                                child: Text(
                                  item,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                            .toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? value) => setState(
                          () {
                            if (value != null) selectedValue = value;
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```